switch language shortcut key problem xfce4
Using us,ir in my xfce4 desktop, I set "Win+Space" to change the language. It switches from us to ir, but not backward. Other combinations like "both shifts" or "alt+shift" work fine.
After some research I found this, but I cannot figure out how does he (check Ghost User's solution) change the output of xkbcomp :0 - command. Where is that file?
